# How to query a data from a column containing range in SQLquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called the `scholars_` table, and one of its columns has the name of `validity` which contains data like this:

```
2016-2019 
2016-2020 
2016-2017 
2018-2019
```

What I want to achieve is to get the `scholarID` of the scholars where their `$validity` is in the `validity` column.

For example the variable is `$year=2017` and I only want to select those `scholarIDs` which have the `validity` of `2017`. The ouput should be like this:

```
2016-2019
2016-2020 
2016-2017
```

Something like that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is a *really* bad way to store data.  Your `scholars` table should simply have `year_from` and `year_to` columns.

But, sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad decisions.  You can handle this using `substring_index()` in MySQL:

```
where $year between substring_index(range, '-', 1) + 0 and substring_index(range, '-', -1) + 0
```

The `+ 0` just converts each value to a number.

Comment: Thanks man. I admit,I was doing it in the right way. But in my previous projects i separate it from start_date to end_date. Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Do not store data like that. Ideally there should be two columns `validity start` and `Validity end`.

Validity Start should have all the validity starting year and Validity end should have all the validity ending year.

Then the query would be simple as

```
Select * from scholars_
Where 2017 between validity_start and validity_end
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT  scholarID FROM scholars_ WHERE $data BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(validity,1,4), '-', 1) + 0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(validity,6,9), '-', -1) + 0`

`$data = 2015 or something`

Comment: Explanation on what the query does would help. Also, discourage providing ready-made answer.